# Using opencv with cmake errors

Tags: opencv, cmake

So i've been trying to build a github project but it requires opencv, so i installed it according to it's website.

After i tried to build but it gets me this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So I tried to set opencv's location using this:

`cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/c/lib/build_opencv/`

But this time it gets me this error:

`CMake Error: The source directory "C:/lib" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

How can i solve it?

I use windows.

Comment: are you trying this with msys or mingw ? and what did you install, exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the install stage from the OpenCV build dir. Either run `nmake install` or build the `INSTALL` project from the Visual Studio solution, depending on which generator you chose.

This will copy all needed files to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which is `C:\Program Files\OpenCV` by default. Then use this directory as a value for `OpenCV_DIR` in your own project.